# Transforming an inhomogeneous Markov chain to a homogeneous one

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I fail to understand [Cinlar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387878580)'s [transformation of an inhomogeneous Markov chain to a homogeneous one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WMHq.jpg). It appears to me that $\hat{P}$ is not fully specified. Generally speaking, given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$, a measure can be specified either explicitly over the entire $\sigma$-algebra, or implicitly by specifying it over a generating ring and appealing to Caratheodory's extension theorem. However, Cinlar specifies $\hat{P}$ over a proper subset of $\hat{\mathcal{E}}$ that is not a ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We give the condition that $\widehat P$ is a Markow kernel, and we have that 
$$\widehat P((n,x),\{n+1\}\times E)=P_{n+1}(x,E)=1,$$
hence the measure $\widehat P((n,x),\cdot)$ is concentrated on $\{n+1\}\times E\}$? Therefore, we have $\widehat P((n,x),I\times A)=0$ for any $A\subset E$ and $I\subset \Bbb N$ which doesn't contain the integer $n+1$.

Comment: Thank you, Davide. What if $\left\{n+1\right\}\subsetneq I$?

Comment: In this case, the set $I\times E$ has necessarily measure $0$ by $\hat P((n,x),)$, since $\{n+1\}\times E$ concentrated all the measure.

Comment: But $A:=\left\{n+1\right\}\times E \subseteq B:=I \times E$, so we should have $a:=\hat{P}\left(\left(n,x\right),A\right)\leq b:=\hat{P}\left(\left(n,x\right),B\right)$, since $\hat{P}$ is a probability transition kernel, whereas you claim that $a=1,\space b=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I believed you wrote "what if $\{n+1\}$ is not included in $I$", whereas you wrote "what if $\{n+1\}$ is contained in $I$ but not equal". In this case, we have $\widehat P((n,x),I\times A)=P_{n+1}(A)$.

Comment: OK. I think i get it: $\hat{P}\left(\left(n,x\right), I\times A\right) = P_{n+1}\left(x,A\right)\cdot \mathbb 1_I\left(n+1\right)$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Thanks for your reply! I was wondering why $\tilde{X}_t := [t, X_t]$ is homogeneous Markovian? I asked a related question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354864/convert-a-stochastic-process-from-markovian-inhomogeneity-to-markovian-homog.